# Include static functions to symbols table using CMake in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, static-functions

I need to get all C/C++ functions names from disassembled library of android NDK project. Now I see only not static functions. Is there a possibility to include static functions to symbols table?

I am using Android Studio and CMake 3.6.

Comment: Static non-class members are not exported to symbols table.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But maybe there is some way to do this for debugging purposes?